# Git hook that runs when you start the commit process in sourcetree?

Tags: githooks, atlassian-sourcetree

Is there a git hook that runs when I hit the "Commit" button in SourceTree?

What I am trying to do is add everything. I've tried the following, in the file ./git/hooks/pre-commit:

```
#!/bin/sh
git add .
echo "hook added everything!"
```

It runs all right, but the timing is wrong -- it appears to run as a part of actually performing the commit. So what happens is that git first decides that that nothing has been added, so the commit needs to fail. THEN it runs the hook and adds everything. Lastly, the commit fails. If I repeat the commit, it will succeed the second time. But that's wrong on several levels. What I really want is to add everything before it opens up the window for the commit message. Then if I want to un-add some stuff, I should be able to do that in that window. Lastly, when I tell SourceTree to go ahead with the commit, I don't actually want a hook at that point, as I've already configured add/remove the way I want it to be.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://medium.com/@onmyway133/sourcetree-and-pre-commit-hook-52545f22fe10

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you cannot commit in SourceTree unless you have added something by staging it for commit.

You're trying to start the commit process in SourceTree before having staged anything - you simply cannot do that.